# Function terminates early after returning a value C++

Tags: c++, function

I'm writing a program that takes in three strings ie. 123.45/N 23.44/S Location Name, then the user inputs the number of locations they want to compare the distance to, and finally each location, ie.

```
12.23/N 22.22/E LAX
3
15.55/S 23.444/W Brazil Airport
120.44/N 99.54/E Mexico Airport
99.22/N 44.4/W Unnamed Airport
```

Then it prints out the closest distance (in miles) and the distance farthest away.

I've been able to parse the numbers out of the first two strings inputted, and in a separate method which takes the number of lines to input as a parameter, goes through a loop asking for input, and runs two methods that return a value to a variable outside of the function: the farthest away location and the closest location to the starting point.

Here is the method:

```
void getTotalLocations(int amountInput) {
    std::string inputLat, inputLong, inputLoc;
    double inputLatParse, inputLongParse;
    double curLocation;
    // ask user for locations
    for(int i = 0; i < amountInput; i++) {
        // grab input
        std::cin >> inputLat >> inputLong;
        getline(std::cin, inputLoc);
        // parse it
        inputLatParse = numberParse(inputLat);
        inputLongParse = numberParse(inputLong);
        // calculate how far the location is from the starting location
        curLocation = getHaversine(inputLatParse, inputLongParse);
        curLocation = getHaversine(inputLatParse, inputLongParse);
        // find and store the closest and farthest location
        getFarthestTotal(curLocation, inputLat, inputLong, inputLoc);
        getClosestTotal(curLocation, inputLat, inputLong, inputLoc);
    } // end for
}
```

And my getFarthestTotal and getClosestTotal:

```
// get the farthest total
double getFarthestTotal(double curFarthestLoc, std::string farthestLatInput, std::string farthestLongInput, std::string farthestLocInput) {
    if(curFarthestLoc > farthestLocTotal) {
        farthestLocTotal = curFarthestLoc;
        // save the farthest location into strings so we can display them later.
        farthestLatitude = farthestLatInput;
        farthestLongitude = farthestLongInput;
        farthestLocation = farthestLocInput;
    }
    return farthestLocTotal;
}

// get the closest total
double getClosestTotal(double curClosestLoc, std::string closeLatInput, std::string closeLongInput, std::string closeLocInput) {
    if(curClosestLoc < closeLocTotal) {
        closeLocTotal = curClosestLoc;
        // save input user entered
        closeLatitude = closeLatInput;
        closeLongitude = closeLongInput;
        closeLocation = closeLocInput;
    }
    return closeLocTotal;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my function, getTotalLocation completely stops after running getFarthestTotal(), so it never runs getClosestTotal() and therefore I never have any numbers to display afterwards. As far as I know, the function shouldn't just stop after returning one thing, but that's what it seems to do (after testing with print statements).

My display ends up looking like this (also with weird formatting):

```
Start Location: 12.23/N 22.22/E ( LAX)
Closest Location:  ()
Farthest Location: 99.22/N 44.4/W ( Unnamed Airport)
```

And my display method looks like this:

```
void displayOutput() {
    std::cout << "Start Location: " << startLatitude << " " << startLongitude << " (" << startLocation << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Closest Location: " << closeLatitude << " " << closeLongitude << " (" << closeLocation << ") (" << closeLocTotal << " miles) " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Farthest Location: " << farthestLatitude << " " << farthestLongitude << " (" << farthestLocation << ") (" << farthestLocTotal << " miles)" << std::endl;
}
```

So basically, what is going wrong with my function that is causing it to stop? And why then is it also screwing with my output (ie. it doesn't print miles after it hits farthestLocation variable and adds an extra space before the location name)?

Comment: The extra space is because `getline()` picks up where the previous operation left off, which in this case is immediately prior to the second whitespace on each line.

Comment: How did you determine that `getClosestTotal` wasn't getting called? Did you add logging to it?

Comment: You should use reference to fill output parameters. Not `double getClosestTotal(double curClosestLoc, std::string closeLatInput ...` but `double getClosestTotal(double curClosestLoc, std::string & closeLatInput...`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I made a print statement right after getFarthestTotal() that just said "test". If anything pasted getFarthestTotal were to execute, that would get printed 3 times. However, nothing was printed.

Comment: Look, you're modifying a variable `closeLatInput`, wich is a **copy** of `inputLat` you gave as a parameter while called `getClosestTotal`. If you'll change the type of `closeLatInput` to reference `std::string & closeLatInput` you'll fill actual variable `inputLat`

Comment: @borisbn For some reason, it still fills the farthest input variables, but entirely skips the getClosest variables that it should be filling :(

Comment: @Alex did you read what borisbn just wrote?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yep. And I edited the parameters to include references.

double getClosestTotal(double curClosestLoc, std::string &closeLatInput, std::string &closeLongInput, std::string &closeLocInput);